# PHP strange behavior.Different outcome on server and localhost

Tags: php

I ran into weird trouble with php.I have script that checks folder for articles ( and very similar script that checks folder for images ) and based on that creates article menu ( or gallery)

On my localhost this works fine , and finds all files and handles them as expected.
On real server though , both scripts break unexpectedly after few files.

Image check script is this

```
function GalleryList() {
echo '
    <div class="GalleryGrid">
      <ul>';
      error_reporting(E_ALL);

      $thumbs = array_diff(scandir('images/Thumbs'),array ('..','.','Thumbs.db'));
      foreach ($thumbs as $key => $current) {
      $imagelist[filectime('images/Thumbs/'.$current)] = $current;
      }
      krsort($imagelist);


      foreach ($imagelist as $key => $thumb) {
        $fullImage = substr($thumb,6);


       echo '<li><a href="images/'.$fullImage.'"><img src="images/Thumbs/'.$thumb.'"> </a> </li>'.PHP_EOL;

      }
      echo '</ul>';




}
```

Article checking is almost the same script , only different folders and different output HTML.There are no differences in permissions.
Needless to say I get no errors.

Comment: You must get errors. Can you access the directories on the server? Do they contain articles and images? Enable error reporting `error_reporting(~0);` and tell us the errors.

Comment: What PHP version(s)? Also, when you say it "breaks unexpectedly", is that a crash or just exiting the loop? have you tried doing a `print_r()` of the array to prove it contais what you expect it to?

Comment: You say you get no errors, but are you sure you are logging or displaying them? error_reporting on its own wont show you any errors if display_errors is false

Comment: When I print_r() the array , it only returns those files,which it worked with correctly. php version is 5.4.6 .

Comment: Is this just a simple `Case Sensitive` issue as I see you are using case specific folder names? Is one system Windows and the other *nix

Comment: Nope.Server is unix , and my OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: Try debugging it, output scandir('images/Thumbs') and see if it contains what you expect and check you are in the folder you think you are.

Comment: Two things : Files are in their place.Outputting ONLY the scandir returns all the files.
Meanwhile i reuploaded the entire website,and the script now functions with DIFFERENT files than before. Is it possible there is some kind of error on server side ? How else could it work with some files, and after reupload with different files ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what actually happens when you say it "breaks", my guess is you're running into file permission issues. Perhaps Apache is running as your username or with broad permissions on your localhost, and on your server it is more restrictive?

What happens if you change this:

```
echo '<li><a href="images/'.$fullImage.'"><img src="images/Thumbs/'.$thumb.'"> </a> </li>'.PHP_EOL;
```

to this (code is super simplified on purpose):

```
$fullImagePath = "images/$fullImage";
$fullThumbPath = "images/Thumbs/$thumb";

if (is_readable($fullImagePath)) {
    echo "<li>$fullImagePath is readable</li>".PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo "<li>$fullImagePath is not readable</li>".PHP_EOL;
}

if (is_readable($fullThumbPath)) {
    echo "<li>$fullThumbPath is readable</li>".PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo "<li>$fullThumbPath is not readable</li>".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Now you'll at least know if you've got a file readability issue.

Comment: Running this script ( thank You btw , i wouldnt think of this ) tells me that files , that worked normally , are readable.No other files.I mean i get no "not readable" outputs.But all of them have the same permission setting.

Comment: Wacky. So what exactly happens when it breaks? Does execution stop and you see perhaps 5 or so thumbnails and that's it? Does the rest of the script execute? Does the page render? Do you get closing HTML and such on the page?

Comment: When it breaks,it exits the loop.It doesnt even seem like an actual error , it just doesnt get all the files in the array.Could i be excluding them by mistake ? Rest of page is normally rendered,with closing HTML and everything.Could there be something wrong with filectime() ?

Comment: Could this fail because the files may have same timestamp of creation , since i uploaded them all at once ?

Comment: You could (and should) remove the `filectime` for testing. filectime returns the time the file was last changed, or FALSE on failure - so perhaps if the file has not been changed, it's not being added to the array.

Comment: It actually works when I upload the files one at a time.I assume , because timestamp was array key,there may be the same timestamp for many of the files , thus conflicted in the array.But thanks for Your help.